# Filter "sub-model" instances from dropdown

Tags: php, templates, pagination, typo3, extbase

I created a new Typo3 extension with the kickstarter
and my `Cities`model has multiple `street` models.
In the template the `street` models of the `city` are listed in a dropdown menu like this:

[image]

---

**The templates code:**

```
<f:section name="main">
    <h1>Single View for City</h1>

    <f:flashMessages renderMode="div" />
    <f:render partial="City/Properties" arguments="{city:city}" />
    Filter:<br>
    <a href='<f:uri.action controller="City" action="showFiltered"  arguments="{city:city, char : 'a'}" />'>A</a>
    <a href='<f:uri.action controller="City" action="showFiltered"  arguments="{city:city, char : 'b'}" />'>B</a>
    <a href='<f:uri.action controller="City" action="showFiltered"  arguments="{city:city, char : 'c'}" />'>C</a>
    <br>
    <f:debug>{city}</f:debug>
    <select onchange="location = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;">
            <option>Select street</option>
        <f:for each="{city.streets}" as="street">
            <option value='<f:uri.action controller="Street"  action="show"  arguments="{street : street}" />' >{street.name}</option>
        </f:for>
    </select>
    <br>
    <f:link.action action="list">Back to list</f:link.action><br />
    <br>
    <f:link.action action="new">New City</f:link.action>
</f:section>
```

Now i need to **filter the entries** by their first character **using the Links above the Dropdown**
(A, B, C).
E.g. after clicking `A` only `Aviation` and `Automation` would be shown...

When i dump out `city` i get this: [image]

But in don't know how to access the streets in my `showFiltered` action:

```
public function showFilteredAction(\Vendor\CollectionPlan\Domain\Model\City $city) {
        $char = $this->request->getArgument('char');

        $this->view->assign('city', $city);
        $this->view->assign('char', $char);
    }
```

to build something like this:

```
public function showFilteredAction(\ActiView\CollectionPlan\Domain\Model\City $city) {
        $char = $this->request->getArgument('char');

        /* This is pseudocode to demonstrate my idea */
        foreach($city => street as $street){  /* Loop through the streets of the city model */
            if(!$street => name.startsWith($char)){ /* Check if the streets name starts with the filter key */
                $street.remove(); /* If it doesn't  remove it from the city variable */
            }
        }
        $this->view->assign('city', $city);
        $this->view->assign('char', $char);
    }
```

TL;DR
**How can i access the streets of the city model in my controller action to check if they start with the given key?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each field that you access via dot notation within fluid controllers has getter and setter (at least if you created it with Extension Builder), what's more you shouldn't remove street from collection as persistence manager will remove them, instead add to your City model *transient* with type i.e. of array , let's name it `$streetsFilteredTransient` and create a getter which will filter the streets:

Just put this to your City model, and **fix** the param of `GeneralUtility::_GP` method

```php
/**
 * The transient field in model is that which haven't a declaration
 * in TCA and field in SQL file
 * so it's ideal for *processing* other fields...
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $streetsFilteredTransient = array();

/**
 * Returns array of street objects which names begins with char,
 * or all streets if no char is given
 *
 * @return array Array of objects
 */
public function getStreetsFilteredTransient() {

    // As model has no access to request you need to fetch the `char` argument *manually*
    $arguments = \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility::_GP('tx_flysites_show');
    $char = (!is_null($arguments) && isset($arguments['char'])) 
        ? htmlspecialchars($arguments['char']) 
        : false;

    foreach ($this->kinds as $street) {
        if (!$char || $this->startsWith($street->getName(), $char))
            $this->streetsFilteredTransient[] = $street;
    }
    return $this->streetsFilteredTransient;
}


private function startsWith($haystack, $needle) {
    $haystack = strtolower($haystack);
    $needle = strtolower($needle);
    $length = strlen($needle);
    return (substr($haystack, 0, $length) === $needle);
}
```

and use it in the view as:

```
<f:for each="{city.streetsFilteredTransient}" as="street">
    ...
</f:for>
```

Comment: Im a little stuck trying to get the _GP working. i replaced the param with tx_collectionplan_showFiltered in my case (assuming that i need the tx_key_nameOfTheAction. but it returns NULL

Comment: OK i got it it using GeneralUtilities _GET() instead of _GP and then accessing it via `$arguments["tx_collectionplan_ftcplan"]["char"]`